# How to create GTM data layer variable with complex array

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

In Google Tag Manager a pre-defined variable type of "Data Layer Variable" exists with an input for the variable name. In a standard single level of key/value pairs this is easy.

`var dataLayer = [{"mykey":"myvalue"}];`

Given that data layer you'd just use `mykey` as your variable to input into GTM. However, if you use the CEDDL spec (http://www.w3.org/2013/12/ceddl-201312.pdf) structure you end up with a deeply nested array:

```
dataLayer = [
  {
    "product": [
      {
        "category": {
          "primaryCategory": "Auto Loans"
        },
        "productInfo": {
          "productID": "1",
          "productName": "PurchaseLoan",
          "description": "Auto finance loan"
        },
        "security": [
          "Analytics",
          "Personalization",
          "Recommendations"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So the real question is: **how do I access the value of "productName" in the above example?**

In standard Javascript you might access it like so:
`dataLayer[1].product[0].productInfo.productName`
or
`dataLayer.1.product.1.productInfo.productName`

... but neither of these options work (with or without `dataLayer.1` as the first node).

This is the UI to enter the variable name:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define your DataLayer variable in GTM, you don't need to specify "dataLayer" in the variable name, ie. it should just be:

```
product.0.productInfo.productName
```

Comment: I had tried this before and it didn't work, but I had to adjust the trigger to fire on DOM ready instead of Page View.